# Symfony 2 - Handling multiple entity listeners on one Entity

Tags: symfony

Lets say I have a entity `Product` and I have a entity ListenerA (`preUpdate`, `prePersist`) for it inside my application.

```
class ListenerA {
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    ...
}
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    ...
}
```

Lets say that the `Product` entity has a property `visible` (bool) and for every update on that entity the `visible` might change either 1 or 0 depending on some logic.

Also in that Symfony application, there is a PHP package came from private repository. This package is taking care of tracking the entity changes on all entities. It has a `ListenerB` that keeps track on all the entities. It uses also the same Doctrine used in the application. On `onFlush` this listener will push the chnages into AWS streaming service.

My problem is for example there was a record that will be updated.
Ofcourse the `two listeners` (`ListenerA` and the `ListenerB`) will be triggered.

Product
id: 1
title: 'some title'
property1: 1
property2: 1
property3: 1
visible: 1

**For example the business rule is when the entity was changed or updated and if property1, property2 and property3 are true, the visibility of the Product must set to true, else it will be false.**. That rule was set on the entity Listener.

So if I change for example the `property3` = 0 then the `visible` must now be `false`.

But as I mentioned there is also another listener `ListenerB` on the PHP package that keeps track also on the changes on that entity.

The problem is that when the `ListenerB` on that PHP package was triggered it doensnt get the **updated** changes on the `Product`'s `visible` property which was triggered by `ListenerA` (implements business logic).

For example the `visibility` of the `Product` is **1** and it was pushed by `ListenerB` to stream but then `ListenerA` changed it to **0** for some logic.

The data pushed to stream was not the updated value.

I need to track the last changes made on `ListenerA` before pushing changes on `ListenerB`.

Most likely I have limited access to the `ListenerB`. I have full access to edit the code on `ListenerA`.

Do you have any suggestions or work arounds for this?

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

When definning a listener in general you can specify a `priority`.

The listener with the **highest** priority is executed **first**

```
services:
    app.listener.a:
        class: Acme\Listener\AListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, priority: 100 }

services:
    app.listener.b:
        class: Acme\Listener\BListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, priority: 50 }
```